# Core Plot: Is it possible to enable the user to pinch-scale a graph on the x-Axis but not on the y-Axis?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I want that the user can zoom in/out a graph only on a single axis.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a plot space delegate. Implement the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method. For the coordinate that you don't want to change, just return the old `xRange` or `yRange`.

Comment: I assume this is right, though I haven`t tried, because I don't require feature this anymore...